# Using jQuery / HTML5 to animate a circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, css

For a personal project, I'm tyring to make a timer application (for controlling Poker blind schedules). I know there are several solutions already on the market, but for reasons which are too lengthy to go into here, we need a bespoke system. Although the output template of the system will ultimately be definable by the end user, we would like to include a widget which shows a circle that gets animated as the time counts down. Here's an illustration of a working example, showing the yellow circle and what we'd like to achieve (or something similar, anyway):

[image: How to animate the circle?]

My question is, how would one code the animation as shown below using either jQuery or raw HTML5 / CSS3 animations? This is for a web application using jQuery, so there are no other library options I can use.

Advanced thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use HTML5, canvas is probably your best bet. Mozilla has some decent [tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes) on drawing arcs. This should be enough to get you started.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasid'),
    width = canvas.width,
    height = canvas.height,
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawTimer(deg) {
  var x = width / 2, // center x
      y = height / 2, // center y
      radius = 100,
      startAngle = 0,
      endAngle = deg * (Math.PI/180),
      counterClockwise = true;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, height, width);
  ctx.save();

  ctx.fillStyle = '#fe6';

  // Set circle orientation
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.rotate(-90 * Math.PI/180);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
  ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
  ctx.fill();
}

setInterval(function() {

  // Determine the amount of time elapsed; converted to degrees
  var deg = (elapsedTime / totalTime) * 360;

  drawTimer(deg);

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great start!

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with CSS3 and jQuery.

Check out my example here http://blakek.us/css3-pie-graph-timer-with-jquery/ which with slight modification you could make the timer look how you want it.

Comment: Your pie graph timer with Jquery is exactly what I was looking for for a project, thank you so much for sharing it!

Comment: Indeed!  Excellent project, Kus!  Going to get a lot of use out of this.  Wish I had more points to mod this one up.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 you can draw in a canvas. 
For example:

```
// Create the yellow face
context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
context.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
context.beginPath();
context.arc(100,100,50,0,Math.PI*2,true);
context.closePath();
context.stroke();
context.fill();
```

[Link](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/how-to-draw-with-html-5-canvas/)

Answer (score 1):

You should really check out [Processing](http://processing.org/)!

Especially [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/). There have been some [interesting things](http://blogs.btk-fh.de/bliz/?p=58) made with it for iPhone

Answer (score 0):

First solution i can think of is [html5 canvas](http://www.google.bg/search?q=html5%20canvas) implementation. From the example above it becomes clear we're talking mobile, so what support does canvas get around mobile browsers i can't tell. developer.mozilla.org provides [sufficient documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/canvas). Using canvas to achieve such count down should be pretty simple task. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Canvas arc command [(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes#Arcs) is probably what you're looking for.  Just decrease the end angle over time to have your timer decrease.