# Create javascript countdown

Tags: javascript, geometry, fill

Good day to all.

I need to create a graphical countdown in js. The algorithm for the timer is ordinary. But I need to create a circle filled with a color (lets say green, doesn't matter) and while the counter goes down the circle gets fill with another color. So what I basically need to do is fill a circle with color.

First I thought to simulate some lines inside the circle (from center to margin) and fill it with them. The problem is how to generate lines... and I got to the conclusion that I should generate points to generate lines to fill the circle and even though the code is easy to write sounds like quite a resource eater.

Second option would be to use a drawing library but I fear that it would do the same thing.

So... any ideas how to implement this without wasting too much resources?

Note: The circle must be fill in a circular way... like skill reuse in games for example. (like a clock)

Comment: Hi, you might want to take a look at javascript libraries for making games. They'll already be heavly optimised for performance so might give you a good headstart.

Comment: Ty... I try find some. Any example pls?

Comment: depending on which browsers you need to support, `<canvas>` seems ideal for this.

Comment: You can create circles in modern browsers (that support the CSS3 "border-radius" property) trivially.  Make a `<div>` (or whatever) a particular width & height (like 100px), then set its "border-radius" to half that (50px).  Bingo, instant circle. Color is equally trivial with CSS.

Comment: Edited question. The circle must be filled in a circular way not from top to bottom... that is trivial.

Comment: "The circle must be fill in a circular way" ... What does that mean?

Comment: Do you mean filled like a clock zozo?

Comment: Sorry zozo, I've not really used game engines myself, but a quick search for "canvas game engine" will probably turn up some results. Or dailyjs.com is a good resource for libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think of is to use the [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com) graphis library which allows your code to draw SVG (or VML on older IE). Look at the source of this demo (which basically does what you want):

http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html

The key to understanding the code is understanding this line:

```
path = [["M", 300, 300 - R], ["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]];
```

And the key to understanding that line is to first understand SVG path specification:

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html

Answer (score 1):

What about to use html5 canvas: with it you can draw arc.

See http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-arcs/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post (using canvas): [Using jQuery / HTML5 to animate a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755765/using-jquery-html5-to-animate-a-circle)

Or if you want to do it yourself with an easy CSS, HTML:

1. You can make a image with a transparent circle in it.
2. Make a div with a position relative and the size of the image, and the default color of the circle
3. Make a div with the overlay background color, absolute positioned width 100% bottom 0.
4. Make a div where the image is as background image width 100% height 100% (so the image is over the default background color.

When the timer ticks out, and you know on what percentage it is, you can change the height of the div you made on step 3. But you won't see any angles on the lines.

Comment: If I understand corectly what you wanna say this will fill my circle from top to bottom not in a circular way. (Probably that's my fault, I edit the question to specify that)

Comment: Yeah that's top to bottom, but I added a link to circular filling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find what you are looking for here:

http://dev-tips.com/featured/css-tip-how-to-make-ircles-without-images

There is a complete tutorial on how to create circles using css3, it won't work very well in older browsers tho.